# Apple Pay, Can we disable Email, Phone and Address editing?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, applepay

In my app the users should have input all the info above before they came to the Apple Pay button, so I will just get the data from the data manager and pre-populate the sheet.

I know it's not kinda the right way to implement Apple Pay but this will just be a quick implementation of Apple Pay and the UI will be improved in a future release.

So just wondering can we disable Email, Phone and Address editing in the Apple Pay sheet.

Thank you!

Comment: Tell your marketing guys that by doing non-standard things during the payment process they will lose revenue because people won't trust them.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the shipping information why are you requesting it in the Apple Pay sheet at all? Simply have your `PKPaymentRequest` not request it. There is no way to make the fields in the Apple Pay sheet read-only, so that is probably your best workaround.